# tkinter - how to bind just control, not control+key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, bind, key-bindings

In Python 3 Tkinter, how do I bind just the control key to a widget, not `<control-key>`?
Normally, it's required to have another key also bound to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to bind `<Control_L>` and `<Control_R>`

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_press(event):
    print(event)

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Control_L>', on_press)
root.bind('<Control_R>', on_press)
root.mainloop()
```

Eventually you can use `<Key>` which is executed with every key and then check `event.keysym` or `event.code`

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_press(event):
    print(event)
    print(event.keysym in ('Control_L', 'Control_R'))
    print(event.keycode in (37, 105))

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Key>', on_press)
root.mainloop()
```